# cannot convert int to string simple age program

Tags: c#, string, int

I am having an odd problem with my program. I want to print out my first name, last name and age and I feel like there is a simple solution here that I am just not seeing.

Here is my code:

```cs
string firstname; //the data type that is named and initialised 
string lastname;
string userAge;
int age;

//takes user input 
Console.Write("please enter your first name - "); 

//stores user input 
firstname = Console.ReadLine(); 

Console.Write("please enter your last name - ");

lastname = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("please enter your age - ");

userAge = Console.ReadLine();

//this is a bit of useless code I was playing around with earlier     
//age = Console.Readline();              

userAge = Convert.ToInt32(age);

//prints user input to screen the 0 is the position
Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0} {1}", firstname,lastname + "and your age is",age); 

//pauses the program for 1000 mlseconds so you can see what the result is 
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Could you explain what part of it isn't working? What do you see? What do you expect? It will likely be obvious to experienced developers, but they are important details when writing up a high-quality question.

Comment: oh sorry userAge = convvert.ToInt32(age); has an error saying that you cannot simplicity convert type int to string I want to print to the screen my first name last name and age the age part is not working because it does not display the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving you that error because `ToInt32` takes a `string` as an input and you're giving it an `int`. Instead, you should give it the `string` and get the `int` as a result:

```
userAge = Console.ReadLine();            
age = Convert.ToInt32(userAge);
```

But really, you don't need to convert anything. Instead, keep everything as strings. Also, your use of `WriteLine` is a little misformed:

```
string firstname;
string lastname;
string userAge;

//takes user input 
Console.Write("please enter your first name - "); 

//stores user input 
firstname = Console.ReadLine(); 

Console.Write("please enter your last name - ");

lastname = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("please enter your age - ");

userAge = Console.ReadLine();  

//prints user input to screen the 0 is the position
Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0} {1} and your age is {2}.", 
        firstname, lastname, userAge); 

//pauses the program for 1000 mlseconds so you can see what the result is 
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Comment: how would I do this if I wanted to keep my age as an int though

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
age = Convert.ToInt32(userAge);
```

And:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Your name is {firstname} {lastname} and your age is {age}");
```

$ allows string interpolation to put variables between {} in the string.

You may use TryParse instead of Convert that raise an exception if an non number is entered or can't fit in the int, on uint because age must be positive:

```
uint age;  // instead of int
```

```
uint.TryParse(userAge, out age);
```

So in case of error, age is 0.

You can also test the result of this method that is false in case of error, to act, for example:

```
do 
{ 
  Console.Write("please enter your age - ");
  userAge = Console.ReadLine();
}
while ( !uint.TryParse(userAge, out age) )
```